# PHP error "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings." when using $_GET

Tags: php, get

I'm getting the error that many have seen when upgrading from PHP 5.2.9 to PHP 5.3.0, but oddly, the error is showing up as the result of a reference to a $_GET variable, not anything to do with a timezone setting.

Here's the error:

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

Has anyone else seen this same thing, and found a way to resolve it without simply changing the error_reporting level?

Thanks.

Comment: How is this error manifesting? An example would be nice...

Comment: Also you say it has nothing to do with the timezone and then tag it as timezone?

Comment: @Chris, I tagged it as timezone because the error mentioned the timezone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also had that error, when I upgraded from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3. I solved that by setting the corresponding server timezone in my php.ini:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"
```

Following http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php, since PHP 5.3 a `E_WARNING` is thrown if the timezone was not set.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use lower case for "PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1":

date.timezone = "america/new_york"